# how to protect your drawables, xml files and databases?

Tags: java, android, apk

Is there any effective way to protect our android resources other than ProGuard that isn't enough effective?

Comment: You simply **can't**.

Answer (score 1):

No, and you're wrong to be worried about it.  You xml files and drawables don't take months.  They're the absolute least valuable parts of your product.  The drawables can literally be captured by a screenshot anyway.  And if you managed to turn off screenshots, they could be captured by taking a picture of the screen with a camera.  So focus on more important things, like making your product more compelling.

You're basically complaining about stuff that's true for any product ever made.  If it runs on hardware that you don't physically control, people can access it in any way they want.  Android is actually more protected than the average windows/max/linux application.  But what you want  isn't possible so long as they actually have to run it-  that means that the OS needs to be able to access those resources.  And anything the OS can do, the person owning the device can replicate.